# Automating Lotus Notes Text Style with perl?

Tags: perl, lotus-notes, ole

I'm trying to automate the sending of an email with an embedded attachment and some text that implements HTML code but it seems that the code that I am using will not allow me to create an HTML bolded text or a unordered list. To double check I created the code in vba then passed it through a vba to perl converter and it matched up with what I had written. Here is the part of my script that handles creating the text and embedded attachment in the email:

```
my $richStyle = $Document->NotesRichTextStyle();
$richStyle->{'PassThruHTML'} = 1;

my $Body = $Document->CreateRichTextItem('Body');

$Body->AppendText(">>EOT");
$Body->AppendStyle($richStyle);
**$Body->AppendText("<b>HELLO</b>");**
$Body->EmbedObject(EMBED_ATTACHMENT,'','$filename','$name');
```

I get this error:

> Not a HASH reference at line $richStyle->{'PassThruHTML'} = 1;

The main point of this code was so that i could use HTML Tags inside the email

Comment: On which line is the error occurring?  I'm wondering if that "EMBED_ATTACHMENT" has any meaning in Perl?  In LotusScript it represents the integer 1454, so use that number instead if you think that's an issue?

Comment: its on the $richstyle{'PassThruHTML'} line sry I forgot to state that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess:

```
my $richStyle = $Document->NotesRichTextStyle();
```

From the designer help:

```
Set notesRichTextStyle = notesSession.CreateRichTextStyle( )
```

You need to create the notesRichTextStyle using the session.

Comment: okay so I did that and it stopped giving me the error, but It did do what I wanted it to do which is use the HTML <B></B> Tags

Comment: I do not understand your comment. What is the issue now?

Comment: well the original purpose of this code was to embed HTML code inside the email, although creating the rich text style compiled without error it didn't do what it was supposed to

Comment: Consider this http://www.codestore.net/store.nsf/unid/BLOG-20091022-0419 approach (codestore)

Comment: To keep things simple, I suggest building the complete email in html (as described in the article), or stick with the richtext format (notesRichTextStyle.Bold to make something bold)

Comment: hmm, i guess i will stick with the richtext format, but also do you know how I can create a list using the richtext format? Theres nothing in the NotesRichTextStyle class

Comment: @Shahab let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1887/discussion-between-jasper-duizendstra-and-shahab)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to create an HTML mail?
In that case, it would be better to use the MIME entity classes to generate native HTML mails and not to rely on the NotesRichText to HTML conversion.

You can find more info on the MIME entity in the Designer Help: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_NOTESMIMEENTITY_CLASS_OVERVIEW.html

Answer (score 0):

```
$ perl -Mdiagnostics -e " []->{1}=2 "
Not a HASH reference at -e line 1 (#1)
    (F) Perl was trying to evaluate a reference to a hash value, but found a
    reference to something else instead.  You can use the ref() function to
    find out what kind of ref it really was.  See perlref.

Uncaught exception from user code:
        Not a HASH reference at -e line 1.
 at -e line 1
```

so whatever NotesRichTextStyle returns doesn't like `->{...}` so maybe use `->SetProperty...` or something else :/